# How can I generate apache thrift JS files to proper es6 for Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, thrift

When I generate thrift files using

```
thrift -r --gen js:node,ts,es6,with_ns -out some_dir/ input.thrift
```

The issue is that is does not generate proper JS es6.

If I use only the `js:node` option, when I bundle my files using webpack, it does not play nicely with my React code.

I get the following error when building my React app

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' error
```

Comment: file a ticket and add a test case